# variable result might not have been initialized

Tags: java

error showing in the last line as

> :::: variable result might not have been initialized

this is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int n1, n2, result;
    char oper;
    n1=1000;
    n2=200;
    oper= '+';

    if(oper == '+')
        result=n1+n2;
    else if(oper == '-')
        result= n1-n2;
    else if(oper == '*')
        result= n1*n2;
    else if(oper == '/')
        result= n1/n2;
    else if(oper == '%')
        result= n1%n2;

    System.out.println("Answer: "+result);
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize your result variable like int n1,n2,result=0;

Comment: `result` won't be initialized as you are only giving it a value within the `if` and `else if` statements.  Also, on a sidenote, please use `oper.equals("+")` instead of `oper == '+'`

Comment: the error states the exact issue, the variables have not been initialized!!!

Comment: @Codeer you can compare char with ==

Comment: @notyou Ah you're right. I overlooked the fact it was a char.

Comment: Thank you for the instant message this help me alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line should be:

```
int n1, n2, result=0;
```

`result` variable was not initialized nor it could be calculated from the code, hence the compiler thinks it won't find the value of the variable. Thus its giving compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand why you got this error:

1. In case of **method's local variable**, Java guarantees that the variable is properly initialized before it's used.
2. Variable `result` may miss getting initialized in case none of the `if-else if` clause gets satisfied. Note that you have not put any `else` clause at end to update variable `result` before it get used in this statement `System.out.println("Answer: "+result);`